# how to avoid lowmemorykiller closing my service

Tags: android, low-memory

I am building a service for android 9 and found that in some situations it is closed by the android system

When looking at the logcat it seems to be killed by the lowmemorykiller

I have two questions:

1. in android manifest i set an `intent-filter android:priority="1000"`, should that solve the issue?
2. what is the suggested stress test to simulate low memory conditions for testing? A source code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `android:priority="999"` or less.

> SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY  Constant Value: 1000
>   Applications should never
>   use filters with this or higher priorities.

2. **adb shell am send-trim-memory com.example.app MODERATE**

*[HIDDEN|RUNNING_MODERATE|BACKGROUND|RUNNING_LOW|MODERATE|RUNNING_CRITICAL|COMPLETE]*

(Note that this command is available for devices with API >= 21)

Also I had a lot of situations when I needed "unstoppable" service, so I wrote my library. You can try it here: https://github.com/iardelian/Revive-S

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.